# Xrm.Navigation.openConfirmDialog return null

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm, xrm

I am using `Xrm.Navigation.openConfirmDialog`for confirmation in Dynamics CRM. I wonder if it can return a value on success or failure.

Below is my source code:

```
function confirmationBox(promptText, w, h) {
    var confirmationStrings = {
        text: promptText, title: "ConfirmationBox",
        cancelButtonLabel: "No", confirmButtonLabel: "Yes"
    };
    var confirmationDimension = { height: h, width: w };
    Xrm.Navigation.openConfirmDialog(confirmationStrings, confirmationDimension).then(
        function (success) {
            if (success.confirmed) {
                console.log("Confirmed");
                return true;
            }
            else {
                console.log("Not Confirmed");
                return false;
            }

        });
}
```

and here in below I am calling this function, but the method return `null` all cases. Any one help to understand why it is not returning anything.

```
var temp = confirmationBox(promptText, 350, 450);
console.log(temp);
```

Answer (score 0):

The success and error functions are just callbacks. The openConfirmDialog does not return the result of your callback functions.

You could change your function, such that your success callback is passed through.

```
function confirmationBox(promptText, w, h, callback) {
var confirmationStrings = {
    text: promptText, title: "ConfirmationBox",
    cancelButtonLabel: "No", confirmButtonLabel: "Yes"
};
var confirmationDimension = { height: h, width: w };
Xrm.Navigation.openConfirmDialog(confirmationStrings, confirmationDimension).then(
    function (success) {
        if (success.confirmed) {
            callback();
        }
        else {
            console.log("Not Confirmed");
            return false;
        }

    });
}
```

Disclaimer, this code might need tweaks to work.

Comment: You could also return Promise and handle that

Answer (score 0):

openConfirmDialog return promise

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/developer/model-driven-apps/clientapi/reference/Xrm-Navigation/openConfirmDialog

so you can use something like this

```
var confirmationBox = function(promptText, w, h) {
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
      var confirmationStrings = {
          text: promptText, title: "ConfirmationBox",
          cancelButtonLabel: "No", confirmButtonLabel: "Yes"
      };
      var confirmationDimension = { height: h, width: w };
      Xrm.Navigation.openConfirmDialog(confirmationStrings, confirmationDimension).then(
         function (success) {
             if (success.confirmed) {
                console.log("Confirmed");
                resolve(true);
             }
             else {
                console.log("Not Confirmed");
                resolve(false);
            }

        }, function (error) {
            reject(error);
        });
   }
}


confirmationBox(promptText, 350, 450).then(function(result){
  console.log(result);
}).catch(function(error){
  //handle error
  console.log(error);
});
```